# JSP pageContext Nullpointer

Tags: java, jsp, inheritance, nullpointerexception, taglib

I'm trying to build a common class for my JSP TagLib classes
I have

```
class MyTag extends CustomTag
{
   public int doEndTag()
   {
      JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut(); <-- this one works fine
   }
}
class CustomTag extends BodyTagSupport
{
   public CustomTag()
   {
      JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut(); <-- this one throws me a Nullpointer
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I could create a extra method in the parent and call it from the child from doEndTag() but it would be much nicer with the Constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first class by the time `doEndTag()` is called, the `pageContext` has been set.  In your second class, `pageContext` has not been set and therefore is `null`.  That is what is causing your null pointer exception.
See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag.html#setPageContext%28javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext%29) for more details.

Comment: But isn't the parent constructor called before the child?

Comment: I believe the constructor is not calling setPageContext(). According to the doc: `This method is invoked by the JSP page implementation object prior to doStartTag()`.

Comment: OK, so do you know of any other way to have pageContext in a parent class?

Comment: Like you described, it seems you will have to create a method in the parent (`doStartTag()` or `doEndTag()`) and have the child call it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to implement the doStartTag(), but I don't see it working out.  Thanks for the help so far, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Funny, it totally worked. doStartTag() of the parent class is called when creating an object of the child class. I don't know how, but nvm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change to the below codes and have a more try:

```
class CustomTag extends BodyTagSupport {    
      public CustomTag()    {
           JspWriter out = super.pageContext.getOut(); 
      } 
}
```